# weird end of program error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

im getting a weird error in my program. my compiler is telling me :

```
expected `}' at end of input 
expected unqualified-id at end of input 
expected `,' or `;' at end of input
```

and its highlighting the last line of my code, which is the closing bracket for my main() function. i have commented out all of the code in int main(), but it still refuses to compile. i checked for missing ";" and theres nothing. SciTE checks parentheses and brackets and stuff, so i know everything is closed properly. i dont seem to be doing anything crazy at all

would including classes cause these errors?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "commands.h"


int main(){

}
```

if a problem were in commands.h, would it manifest at the last bracket?

Comment: Do you have any non-ASCII character?  Check the space and quotes, if you copied them from web/word.

Comment: When you `#include` a file, the compiler essentially inserts the copy of that file into your source code.  So yes, if a file you're `#include`-ing has an error like a missing semicolon after the class definition, it can manifest itself in your source file.

Comment: nope. i only use typed chars, and i typed everything myself

Comment: That file looks fine, can you show us `commands.h`?

Comment: Is that the ONLY error the compiler is giving you?  How about warnings?

Comment: wow. i found the error. there was an extra bracket in one of the public functions. oops. now there are other errors that im going to need to clean up. i guess this thread may be closed

Comment: the only warning was that there is no newline at the bottom

Comment: The better compilers will tell you the line where the unclosed block got opened, something like "unmatched opening brace '{' on line nnn of commands.h".  Unfortunately, it looks liek g++ doesn't: http://www.ideone.com/8zgby

Comment: @calccrypto:  If you found the error, post it as an answer and accept it to close the topic.

Comment: well, no one really answered it. you guys sort of just led me to the solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably forgot the semicolon after the closing brace on a class or structure definition.

```
class C
{
} // <<-- HERE, semicolon needed
```

One of the other things that can appear there is a variable declaration:

```
class C
{
} c; // <<-- creates a global variable of type "class C"
```

Since a variable name is an *unqualified-id*, this explains your error message.

Comment: nope, unfortunately. i checked for semicolons. there's nothing after the closing bracket of the class except the ";"

Comment: @calccrypto: On every class, including those in header files?

Comment: i found the error. it turns out to be an extra "{" in the class prototypes

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this error, another possibility is that a function's name is used by an included library, so there's a naming conflict. In my case just changing the name of my method worked; before, I was getting this same error.

Comment: Ugh. In my case I'd accidentally left a function definition open. GCC could really do better by pointing out where the greatest open paren level started.